# Swing Button has the method not returning despite an explicit return statement. Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, authentication

I have been creating a log in and sign up pages. In my sign up, I call the Main Application upon successful log in.

In the code below, I try to check for cases in the files (read/write, no database) if username or email exits to give an error. However, if I press on sign up again, it signs up and writes in file.

For example, I have in the username text file =
John
Sam
Vick

and I sign up with Sam, it shows Username already exists. However, when I press again, it registers because when I debugged it seems that it continues after the if statement and does not return outside the
void active listener method.

```
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Save input in directory called registered_users.txt
            String username_fieldd = usernameField.getText();
            String password_fieldd = passwordField.getText();
            String email_fieldd = emailField.getText();
            
            LinkedList<String> userss = new LinkedList<String>();
            while(scan_username.hasNext()) {
                userss.add(scan_username.next());
            }
            
            for (int i=0; i<userss.size(); i++) {
                if (usernameField.getText().equals(userss.get(i))) {
                    dialog.setText("Username already exists.");
                    return;
                }
            
            }


            while (scan_email.hasNext()) {
                if (emailField.getText().equals(scan_email.next())) {
                    dialog.setText("Email already exists.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (usernameField.getText().isBlank()) {
                dialog.setText("Error. Please input a username.");
                return;
            }

            if (emailField.getText().isBlank()) {
                dialog.setText("Error. Please input an email.");
                return;
            }

            if (passwordField.getText().isBlank()) {
                dialog.setText("Error. Please input a password.");
                return;
            }

            if (!passwordField.getText().equals(passwordField_1.getText())) {
                dialog.setText("Passwords do not match.");
                return;
            } else {
                try {
                    userNames.write(username_fieldd + "\n");
                    passwords.write(password_fieldd + "\n");
                    emails.write(email_fieldd + "\n");
                    userNames.close();
                    passwords.close();
                    emails.close();
                }

                catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                dialog.setText("User has been successfully created!");
                MainApplication main_menu1 = new MainApplication();
                main_menu1.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
        }

        });
```

Of course, do not mind that I used a for loop and a while at each instance, I was just trying to figure if they have any different results, but sadly they didn't.

PS: I thought of using a circular linkedlist so that at any point it iterates back but I wasn't able to do it inside the button.

Comment: *"I thought of using a circular linkedlist so that at any point it iterates back"* You seem to have grand ideas.. *"..but I wasn't able to do it inside the button"* but that part suggests you should be studying Java basics at the moment. GUIs are not easy to make. Cross platform, multi-threaded GUIs even harder still. Become confident with the basics of the language using console apps, is what I recommend. Then come back to the GUI and the answer(s) should be obvious.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, however, I am required to develop a basic GUI for my Java code. I know my code isn't efficient but I can not get over that such logical error could occur and register users when they already exist in the file. Anyhow, if you have an idea of any simpler GUI, I'd appreciate it :)